# How do you change the language on Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store, languages

How do you change the language on Google Play? I'm American, so I want it in English. I live in Luxembourg, have a Lux SIM card and bought my phone in Thailand and yet the Google Pay Topics are all in Italian. I lived in Italy years ago but I'm not using anything that I got in Italy. I've tried clearing the cache on the app, but I get the same thing and it's also on my laptop, which I purchased recently in Lux as well. It's really annoying. How can I change it? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to change your account language to English. To do so, you have to log in to your [Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/), click on [Language & Input Tools](https://myaccount.google.com/preferences?pli=1#localization) and change your language to English (United States)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the language for Gmail, Docs, Drive, Search, Calendar, and other Google products with a single setting in your Google Account.

1. Go to your Google Language settings page.
2. Select edit.
3. Select your language and country.

If you’re changing the language on a mobile device, you should also change the language for the device in your device settings.